# Make a div fill up the entire width and height of a table cell with unspecified dimensions

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
table, th, td, div {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td> <td>two</td> <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"> <div>four</div> </td>
    
    <td>five</td> <td>six</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>seven</td> <td>eight</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

The desired result is for the `div` in the table cell to look more like
this:

[image]

Notice the "four" `div` fills the entire width and height of the table cell in the image but not in the code snippet.

There are questions similar to this that suggest using absolute positioning which doesn't work in this exact situation ( per my attempts ) on a table with unspecified width and height. Other answers say there is no way to do this without JavaScript. But those answers were from 2010. Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use table? You can make use of Grid.

Comment: good question @m4n0. My content is tabular data so for semantics: yes. I would rather use a table but I will use a grid if I have to. The question still remains is this possible with html tables?

Comment: negative margin? t

Comment: @TemaniAfif on all sides?

Comment: yes .......... ..

Comment: @TemaniAfif it doesn't work how you'd expect: https://jsfiddle.net/rko2b5jn/. The borders of the div don't move at all.

Comment: position:absolute works fine then: https://jsfiddle.net/1rwonxv6/1/

Comment: ^ but will break for a long content: https://jsfiddle.net/1rwonxv6/2/

Comment: @TemaniAfif it also breaks on mobile: https://imgur.com/qLhPuhr. View my sourcecode here: https://dev-sbx.github.io/x/. I viewed with an iphoneXS on IOS14 in Safari.

Comment: a working solution on chrome only: https://jsfiddle.net/5n039rs6/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif and it *almost* works on mobile as well. Thank you that's a great effort. It even works in firefox but doesn't quite cut the mobile test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many things it seems that as of 2020 stretching a `div` to fill all the available space of a table cell without JavaScript is not possible unless you use absolute/relative positioning.

The downside with absolute positioning is that the cell does not expand with the content inside it and even not expanded the table cell seems to break on mobile ( tested with an iphoneXS on IOS14 )

[dev-sbx.github.io/x](https://dev-sbx.github.io/x)

[image]

The only real solution here seems to be using a CSS Grid layout opposed to an HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

if you are okay with a few classes then you can achieve what you shown in the image.

```css
table,
th,
td,
div {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

.spl {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  border-style: none;
}

.inb {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="inb">
      <div class="spl">four</div>
    </td>

    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>seven</td>
    <td>eight</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you have essentially hidden the `div`s borders and are setting background color on the table cell. This question asks to fill up a table cell with a div because in my project it'ts not as simple as this example. I really need to stretch the `div` itself across the whole cell in every direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery as follows to get the (outer) width and height of that parent `td` and apply it to that `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var cellwidth1 = $('.x1').outerWidth();
  var cellheight1 = $('.x1').outerHeight();
  $('.x2').css({
  'height': cellheight1,
  'width': cellwidth1
  });
});
```

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
table, th, td, div {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 1em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
td.x1 {
  padding: 0;
}
div.x2 {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td> <td>two</td> <td>three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="x1" rowspan="2"> <div class="x2" >four</div> </td>
    
    <td>five</td> <td>six</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>seven</td> <td>eight</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Using vanilla JS is one thing but jquery? For this? O.o

Comment: You wrote: "Any input would be much appreciated", so I don't know what to think of your reaction

Comment: Sorry I do very much appreciate your answer and the time you took. I mentioned in the original question however that I am not using JavaScript. That said there is something I learned from your answer and I appreciate it; it just seems a little heavy handed for something like this ^^. Thanks anyway